# Matching iterating values in js when iterating with a higher step count than 1

Tags: javascript, increment

How do I match values when I use a different iterating step count other than 1?

Please see the example below. I am interating by 5 since 5 is the speed.

But, how do I stop once I come close to 53. How do I detect and stop start from going way past 53 and make it 53?

```js
var start=0;

var value_to_reach=53;
var increment_speed=5;
while(true) {


if(start>value_to_reach) 
{
start-=increment_speed
} else { start+=increment_speed  }



if (start==value_to_reach) { 
console.log("reached :" + value_to_reach); //Obviously this will never happen with the increment being +5."
    }
  if (start>54)
    {
    console.log("Let's break this loop for the sake of stopping this infinite loop. But we couldn't achieve what we want. Not reached " + value_to_reach); 
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you think about `valuetoreach - i` ? is this a math operation you feel confident with?

Comment: I need to start from 0 and increment all the way until the value I need but I can't increment by 1.  I can't use valuetoreach-1 since I need to animate from 0 to the valuetoreach but again the step count can't be 1 or the multiples of the number to reach.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the tip. It's been a while since I've used SO. I will provide a reproducable example.

Comment: Added a minimum reproducable example now.

Comment: Your latest edit doesn't make any sense. Why whould you want to decrease the counter if you're above the `value_to_reach`? Thats guaranteed to end in a infinite loop...

Comment: yeah, I understand that. But here's my situation... it's an animation. The increment_speed is the speed at which it animates. I can't keep the speed as 1. That's the problem. Now, does it make sense?

Comment: Why not just set `start = value_to_reach` in the `if (start > value_to_reach)`?

Comment: because if the object is large, it needs to animate and become smaller to reach size 53. If the object is too small like 10, it needs to animate and become bigger to reach 53.. You see what I mean? Once it reaches size 53, it's the end of the animation.

Comment: Also,for your question on why not set start=value_to_reach, It will never reach 53 because we're incrementing by multiples of 5. Atleast that's what I understand. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: After you reaches to 53 the you want to decrease to 1 and then increment to 53 and then ....?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi, It's not reaching 53 since we're incrementing by multiples of 5. So how to detect if it's close to 53 or not? Not less than or greater than, but near 53.

Comment: in my opinion this is the wrong approach to animation. here is an example of building composable time based based animations in javascript using an animatable mixin/decorator: https://gist.github.com/r3wt/172f61842c5d2a98cc3e49b336b6e988

this only includes two easings, quad and linear. for more complex easings with reference implementations, see here https://easings.net/

Comment: @r3wt , Thank you. That is very interesting however I cannot set the speed even in that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to detect if it's close to 53 or not

You can get total steps by this:

```
var totalRepeation = Math.ceil(value_to_reach / increment_speed);
```

And so you can create counter that increment one by one and check to see last step.

You can try this one:

```js
var start = 0;

        var value_to_reach = 53;
        var increment_speed = 5;

        let totalRepeation = Math.ceil(value_to_reach / increment_speed);

        let i = 0;
        while (true) {
            
            if (start > value_to_reach) {
                start -= increment_speed
            } else { start += increment_speed; i++ }

            if (i + 1 >= totalRepeation) {
                console.log("you are close to 53. the start numbre is: ", start)
                break;
            }


            if (start == value_to_reach) {
                console.log("reached :" + value_to_reach); //Obviously this will never happen with the increment being +5."
            }
            if (start > 54) {
                console.log("Let's break this loop for the sake of stopping this infinite loop. But we couldn't achieve what we want. Not reached " + value_to_reach);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes both your answers are helpful. Thanks for the tip on finding the step count. I never thought of those things.

Answer (score 1):

###### To lower the steps if we're getting close to `target`

In the `while (start <= reach)` loop we can:

- Check if the next iterator is above `reach`

  - If so, lower the iterator
  - Otherwise, keep regular step size
- Increment counter

```js
let start = 0,
    steps = 5,
    reach = 53,
    debug = 0;

while (start <= reach) {
  
  console.log(`Step: ${steps}, current: ${start}`);
  
  // If next iteration will be above reach
  if ((start + steps) >= reach) {
  
    // Set steps to the diff
    steps = (start + steps) - reach;
  }
  
  // Increment
  start += steps;
}
```

This will output:

```
Step: 5, current: 0
Step: 5, current: 5
Step: 5, current: 10
Step: 5, current: 15
Step: 5, current: 20
Step: 5, current: 25
Step: 5, current: 30
Step: 5, current: 35
Step: 5, current: 40
Step: 5, current: 45
Step: 5, current: 50
Step: 2, current: 52
Step: 1, current: 53
```

---

###### If you want to go above `reach`, and then go back to `target`, you can use something like:

```js
let start = 0,
    steps = 5,
    reach = 53,
    debug = 0;

do {
  
  console.log(`Step: ${steps}, current: ${start}`);
  
  // If we're above the target
  if (start > reach) {
  
    // Set steps to negative
    steps = -1;
  }
  
  // Increment
  start += steps;
  
  console.log(`Step: ${steps}, current: ${start}`);
} while (start !== reach)
```

Comment: I understand but in my case, I need to increment if its lesser and decrement if its greater. Despite this situation, I need to match the value. I'll modify the example a bit

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by 'I need to increment if its lesser and decrement if its greater'. Please clarify in the OP.

Comment: Do you see my updated example? It's an animation. I need to keep increasing the size of the object if its too small at a faster speed. (ie increment_speed). if the size of the object is big, I need to keep decreasing it's size until it reaches the desired smaller size. In this case, the size is 53 and the speed is 5. I can't keep the speed as 1.

Comment: Please see my edit, is this in the right direction?

Comment: Yes! It is in the right direction. Nice idea. That works.

Comment: I;ve added another snippet, not sure which one is the one you prefer.

Comment: Mmm, why did you changed the accepted answer? Thought the first snippet was as you'd expected.